# python input() with wide characters (jp or cn) is not working properly on Mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, internationalization

Writing a small dialog on terminal, and it supposed to take unicode input.

When input, the first time looks okay, but if you delete the character using backspace, you cannot fully delete them.

reproduce:

1. create a py file `test.py`
2. write single line in this file `input()`, and save
3. run the file using `python test.py`
4. input any japanese or chinese sentences, e.g. `这是一个测试`
5. then try use backspace to delete, it only can only delete to half of the sentence.

(py ver 3.8)

it seems the delete in the terminal only delete one ascii size, where each wide char takes two.

but in python console it does not have this problem.

any idea?

====

updates:

a screen record: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_jXSF9FxJt4U9_4O-faMyoWPp9mQPdrH/view?usp=sharing

found same problem on Mac+Bash, Mac+Zsh, Ubuntu+Bash, Ubuntu+Konsole

Windows Dos works ok.

Comment: I can't reproduce, copying in that sentence and deleting them allows me like any other string

Comment: This looks like something that would be managed by your terminal application, not by Python. It works correctly on all the Python versions I tried (3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10) on Linux (using the Konsole terminal). 

You should check to see if you can reproduce the behaviour in other terminals. If you can't reproduce it in those terminals, it could be a good idea to report a bug for the terminal you were using. 

Also check if the issue happens when just typing into your shell program (eg ZSH).

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge , I just tried ubuntu, and it has same error.  A screen record here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_jXSF9FxJt4U9_4O-faMyoWPp9mQPdrH/view?usp=sharing , on Mac it works much same.

Comment: ubuntu + Konsole also erroring, but Windows dos is working correctly.

Comment: Very interesting... two things catch my interest: what happens when you hit enter (what string is stored into a variable), and does it also happen in your terminal in general (try typing directly into the shell).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

After some searching, I found a fix for it, which is to add `import readline`:

```
import readline
input()
```

I don't know why `import readline` fixed the problem.